# Can't import static resource in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, static-resources

I've been trying to access static resource in lwc but I can't use @salesforce because it gives me an error of "scoped imports not allowed when a runtime namespace is specified : lwc". I simply can't get rid of runtime namespace since I needed it. Is there a way to use static resource even though a runtime namespace is specified?

[image: This is how I imported my static resource]

Comment: Can you add the code snippet here?

Comment: @rahulgawale that is how I imported my static resource in lwc, but I can't make it work because of the runtime

Comment: @Coleen if you need to specify a namespace, you need 2 underscores after the namespace, example: `import myResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/namespace__resourceReference';` see doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_resources)

Comment: Does the import statement sample format shown here help you (https://ufthelp.com/2020/06/25/using-custom-lwc-inside-vlocity-omniscript/)? Just curious why you are using runtimeNamespace when it is not mentioned in developer guide as an accepted config value?